# Relation between entropy and compressibility of a file

Tags: entropy

Suppose I have an ordered list of bytes (the hexdump of some object file), and wish to calculate the information entropy of this file. My understanding is I can calculate this as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{n=255} -p_n \log_{256}(p_n) 
$$

where $p_n = \frac{(\text{number of n-valued bytes})}{(\text{total number of bytes})}$.

My understanding is that the information entropy should be the theoretical lower bound for the compression ratio for a file. But when calculating the entropy of the standard C library, I get an entropy of ~0.8, when it's possible to compress the standard C library to 40% of the original size using gzip.

What am I misunderstanding here? Perhaps my calculation of $p_n$ is too simplistic, as the value of every byte in a byte stream is not independent of the preceding bytes, in the same way that characters in English text are not independent. Is there a better way to calculate the informational entropy of a file?

Comment: That is how much you can compress individual bytes. If you want the compression ratio for the whole file, you need to look at the probability distribution of files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Probably way too late for you, but as a future reference.

The $p_n$ you calculate is the fraction and not the probability of a complete random event.
Probably there is a lot of correlation in your data.

Suppose you'd have a file of 1MB pure 0, followed by 1MB of pure 1 (or 255 to be more accurate for bytes). Your fraction of bits set to true is 50%, and entropy according to your calculation would be 1 (and thus no compression), but this file could be described/compressed in a few hundred of bytes.

Comment: But how is entropy of a finite series is computed in practice?

Comment: @tst depends if you know the behavior of the symbol source a priori. If you don't know, zipping is actually a good estimator. The compression rate should converge to the entropy. Otherwise, you could use the formula in the original post.